# Deletable Table with TextField on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

### Environment

- Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500)

### Problem

In order to implement editable teble with TextField on SwiftUI, I used `ForEach(0..<items.count)` to handle index.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DummyView: View {
    @State var animals: [String] = ["", ""]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            EditButton()
            ForEach(0..<animals.count) { i in
                TextField("", text: self.$animals[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**However, problems arise if the table is changed to be deleteable.**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DummyView: View {
    @State var animals: [String] = ["", ""]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            EditButton()
            ForEach(0..<animals.count) { i in
                TextField("", text: self.$animals[i]) // Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
            }
            .onDelete { indexSet in
                self.animals.remove(atOffsets: indexSet) // Delete "" from animals
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[`Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` when delete item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZOIW.png)

has been removed from animals and the ForEach loop seems to be running twice, even though animals.count is 1.

```
(lldb) po animals.count
1

(lldb) po animals
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : ""
```

Please give me advice on the combination of Foreach and TextField.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, the reason is in documentation for used ForEach constructor (as you see range is constant, so ForEach grabs initial range and holds it):

```
/// Creates an instance that computes views on demand over a *constant*
/// range.
///
/// This instance only reads the initial value of `data` and so it does not
/// need to identify views across updates.
///
/// To compute views on demand over a dynamic range use
/// `ForEach(_:id:content:)`.
public init(_ data: Range<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content)
```

So the solution would be to provide dynamic container. Below you can find a demo of possible approach.

**Full module code**

```
import SwiftUI

struct DummyView: View {
    @State var animals: [String] = ["", ""]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                EditButton()
                Button(action: { self.animals.append("Animal \(self.animals.count + 1)") }, label: {Text("Add")})
            }
            List {
                ForEach(animals, id: \.self) { item in
                    EditorView(container: self.$animals, index: self.animals.firstIndex(of: item)!, text: item)
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    self.animals.remove(atOffsets: indexSet) // Delete "" from animals
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EditorView : View {
    var container: Binding<[String]>
    var index: Int

    @State var text: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: self.$text, onCommit: {
            self.container.wrappedValue[self.index] = self.text
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "dynamic container", I have difficulties to understand why this solution works...

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 15.2 (15C500b), and possibly before this, a Binding [init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init%28_:content:%29-96gx9) for ForEach has been added, which makes implementation straightforward. However, I feel it might not work well in this case as the state is confirmed for each input, causing the keyboard to close.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DummyView: View {
    @State var animals: [String] = ["", ""]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            EditButton()
            ForEach($animals, id: \.self) { $animal in
                TextField("", text: $animal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

it is because editbutton is IN your list. place it ouside or better in navigationbar.

Comment: No, this won't help.