# SwiftUI: Index out of range when last element gets removed

Tags: arrays, swiftui, lazyvstack

I have a checklist made with LazyVStack, I implemented remove functionality for the checklist items, but for some reason the a**pp crashes with "Index out of range" only when I try to remove the last element**

Here is my code:

```
struct ChecklistView: View {
    // Properties
    // ==========
    @ObservedObject var checklist = Checklist()
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ChecklistViewModel
    @Binding var checklistItems: [ChecklistItem]
    @State var newItemName = ""
    @State var newChecklistItemViewIsVisible = false
    @State var presentAddNewItem = true
    let offlineMode: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(checklistItems) { item in
                    HStack {
                        RowView(checklistItem: $checklistItems[item], viewModel: viewModel)
                            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                            .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                            .padding(.top, 12)
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)

                        Button {
                            //Prints the correct index number for the last element in the array, but when I remove the last element, always crashes.
                            print(index)
                            if let index = checklistItems.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == checklistItems[item].id}){
                                checklistItems.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Text("X")
                        }
                    }

                    Divider()
                        .frame(width: 311)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32)
        .background(backgroundSecondary)
        .cornerRadius(16)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .stroke(borderGray, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Given your `ForEach(checklistItems)`, shouldn't `item` be of type ChecklistItem? But you're subscripting with it as if it's of type Int. This this your actual code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, I changed my forEach to:

```
ForEach(checklistItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    HStack {
                        RowView(
                            checklistItem:
                                Binding(
                                    get: { self.checklistItems[index] },
                                    set: { self.checklistItems[index] = $0 }
                                ),
                            viewModel: viewModel
                        )
                        .padding(.leading, 12)

                        if checklistEditMode {
                            Button {
                                checklistItems.remove(at: index)
                            } label: {
                                Image("XCircle")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                            }
                            .padding(.trailing, 12)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                    .padding(.top, 12)
                    .padding(.bottom, 4)

                    Divider()
                        .frame(width: 311)
                }
```

and it works now with no crashes, Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61434129/swiftui-deleting-last-row-in-foreach/61435489#61435489)

Answer (score 1):

The `item` from your `ForEach(checklistItems) { item in` is not an index into the array
of `checklistItems`, it is a `ChecklistItem`. However you are using it as an index in
the `RowView(checklistItem: $checklistItems[item], ...`. This is not correct.

Try this approach using `indices` to fix your issue:

```
ForEach(checklistItems.indices, id: \.self) { ndx in
    HStack {
        RowView(checklistItem: $checklistItems[ndx], viewModel: viewModel)
            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            .padding(.horizontal, 12)
            .padding(.top, 12)
            .padding(.bottom, 4)

        Button {
            print(ndx)
            checklistItems.remove(at: ndx)
        } label: {
            Text("X")
        }
    }
    Divider().frame(width: 311)
}
```

You can also use this:

```
ForEach(Array(zip(checklistItems.indices, checklistItems)), id: \.0) { ndx, item in
```

Comment: It is highly likely that in this case you don't want to `id` by index. When you add/remove items from `checklistItems`, you are making already existing views change id. This breaks the animations, because the view IDs weren't constant. Instead you should conform `ChecklistItem` to `Identifiable` and then id by `id: \.1.id` in your 2nd piece of code, for example.

Comment: Looks like both solutions still crash my app on last item deletion

Comment: good advice from George. It may "look" like it will crash, but it does not in my tests. To be sure, show us what is in `ChecklistItem`