# SwiftUI: List, ForEach, indices and .onDelete not working when using TextField() - (Index out of range)

Tags: arrays, swift, foreach, swiftui, textfield

I have no idea how get this working - simple array of struct.
When in ForEach I've got `Text(...)` everything works including `.onDelete()`.
When in ForEach I've got `TextField(...)` THEN `.onDelete()` doesn't work any more - `Fatal error: Index out of range`.

```
struct plan : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var planName : String = ""
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pls = [plan(planName: "plan1")]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView  {
            List {
                ForEach (pls.indices, id:\.self) {i in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(pln: self.$pls[i])) {
                        TextField("", text: self.$pls[i].planName)
//                        Text(self.pls[i].planName)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete { (offset) in
                    for i in offset {
                        let sorted = self.pls.sorted {$0.planName < $1.planName}
                        if let found = self.pls.firstIndex(where: { $0.planName == sorted[i].planName }) {
                            self.pls.remove(at: found)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58911168/12299030?

Comment: Thank you very much - that's it ! ;)

Comment: You're welcome. You can vote that answer up if it helped you.