# Index Out Of Range When Using .onDelete -SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

When executing the .onDelete function, I am getting an index out of range. I have successfully used onDelete elsewhere in my app, deleting data directly from core data. This version is to only delete from a list not stored in core data.

I created some temporary lists for testing, and using this .onDelete was successful. The successful test cases were with arrays that already had data in them and did not need to be initialized. The array used in the code below is one that is initialized when the user lands on this page - could this be why it is failing?

There is lots of code inside this struct, but the relevant parts are below:

```
@State var recipeStep: [String]
```

More code, eventually reaching the ForEach causing the problems

```
            List {
                ForEach(0..<recipeStep.count, id: \.self) { index in
                            HStack {
                                Text(String(stepNumber[index]) + ".").bold()
                                TextField("", text: $recipeStep[index]).multilineTextAlignment(.leading).padding(.leading)
                            }
                }.onDelete { (indexSet) in
                    recipeStep.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)}
```

Any thoughts as to why I am getting an index out of range error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by modifying my textfield to work the following way:

```
EditorView(container: self.$recipeStep, index: index, text: recipeStep[index])
```

The solution was found here, posted by Asperi: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58911168/12299030

I had to modify his solution a bit to fit my forEach, but overall it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You loop with `recipeStep` in

```
ForEach(0..<recipeStep.count, id: \.self) { index in
```

While you use both `$recipeStep[index]` and  `stepNumber[index]`

So `recipeStep` and `stepNumber` should be of same size to avoid crashes or better union them in 1 model

Comment: Ah ha! I think you are correct. Any idea on how I can display the actual values n the recipeStep array in my foreach? Currently I am forced to use the index of each, then apply the index value to the subscript of each array. Ideally I would like to do something like ForEach(recipeStep, id: \.self { index in Text(recipeStep) --- but I cannot get that to work

Comment: if you delete from `recipeStep.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)` don't you also need `stepNumber.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)` ???

Comment: I added that piece after you edited your comment, but it still appears to be failing. Is it because they do not execute at the same time?

Comment: I did some additional testing and the source of the issue is related to deleting this line "TextField("", text: $recipeStep[index]).multilineTextAlignment(.leading).padding(.leading)" - I was able to delete the stepNumber separately and it did not cause issues. Could the issue be because I am referring a binding "$recipeStep" and trying to delete that?

Comment: After additional testing, the TextField row is what is causing issues. If I display the recipeStep in Text format, things work. But using textfield causes an error. Thoughts?