# Delete a Binding from a list in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swift3

I am trying to simply delete an element from a list in Swift and SwiftUI. Without binding something in the `ForEach` loop, it does get removed. However, with binding something it crashes with an error `Index out of range`. It seems like the `ForEach` loop is constant, not updating, and trying to render at the specific index.

Example view code:

```swift
@ObservedObject var todoViewModel: TodoViewModel
//...
ForEach(self.todoViewModel.todos.indices) { index in
    TextField("Test", text: self.$todoViewModel.todos[index].title)
        .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.todoViewModel.deleteAt(index)
                }, label: {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                })
            }
        }))                                    
}
```

Example view model code:

```swift
final class TodoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var todos: [Todo] = []
    
    func deleteAt(_ index: Int) -> Void {
        self.todos.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Example model code:

```swift
struct Todo: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String = ""
}
```

Does anyone know how to properly delete an element from a list where it is bound in a `ForEach` loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58911168/12299030?

Comment: Sadly not. I've also noticed this, but you can see in the code that I do not use any range in the `ForEach`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68965407/14476409 best answer. I have searched everywhere. Solution is this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you're enumerating by `indices` and referencing binding by index inside `ForEach`

I suggest you switching to `ForEachIndexed`: this wrapper will pass both index and a correct binding to your block:

```
struct ForEachIndexed<Data: MutableCollection&RandomAccessCollection, RowContent: View, ID: Hashable>: View, DynamicViewContent where Data.Index : Hashable
{
    var data: [(Data.Index, Data.Element)] {
        forEach.data
    }
    
    let forEach: ForEach<[(Data.Index, Data.Element)], ID, RowContent>
    
    init(_ data: Binding<Data>,
         @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Index, Binding<Data.Element>) -> RowContent
    ) where Data.Element: Identifiable, Data.Element.ID == ID {
        forEach = ForEach(
            Array(zip(data.wrappedValue.indices, data.wrappedValue)),
            id: \.1.id
        ) { i, _ in
            rowContent(i, Binding(get: { data.wrappedValue[i] }, set: { data.wrappedValue[i] = $0 }))
        }
    }
    
    init(_ data: Binding<Data>,
         id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>,
         @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Index, Binding<Data.Element>) -> RowContent
    ) {
        forEach = ForEach(
            Array(zip(data.wrappedValue.indices, data.wrappedValue)),
            id: (\.1 as KeyPath<(Data.Index, Data.Element), Data.Element>).appending(path: id)
        ) { i, _ in
            rowContent(i, Binding(get: { data.wrappedValue[i] }, set: { data.wrappedValue[i] = $0 }))
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        forEach
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ForEachIndexed($todoViewModel.todos) { index, todoBinding in
    TextField("Test", text: todoBinding.title)
        .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.todoViewModel.deleteAt(index)
                }, label: {
                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                })
            }
        }))
}
```